# Which sects of Christianity recite verses of God and prostrate to God during the night?

Tags: prayer, comparative-christianity, religious-practice, worship, prostration

I'm looking that this verse if Quran.

> <sub>[Āl ʿImrān:13](https://quran.com/3/113)</sub>
>
> They are not (all) equal. Of the population of the Book (Or: Family of
> the Book; i.e., the Jews and Christians) is an upright nation (who)
> recite the signs (i.e., verses) of Allah at various times of the night
> as they prostrate themselves (to Him).

And wanted to know which sects have instructions for reciting and prostrating at the night.

Based on [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prostration#Christianity) a number of Christians (Oriental Orthodox Christianity, Western Orthodox Christianity, Syriac Orthodox, Indian Orthodox Christians, The Roman Catholic, Lutheran, and Anglican Churches, Eastern Orthodox (Byzantine Rite)) prostrate.

I want to know which groups prostrate **(every) night** and also prostrate to God (but not in the name of the trinity, but **just God**). Based on the comments the criterion that I've specified disqualifies all the groups I mentioned.

So are there any Christian groups that match the criterions mentioned?

Comment: The Christian groups you have mentioned all believe in the Triune God. Why (and how) therefore would (or could) they prostrate themselves before what you term 'just God' ? This question is very unclear indeed and needs to be clarified/

Comment: Most Christians would associate the name of God as being the Most Holy Trinity!

Comment: @KenGraham Right. I'm excluding them mostly in my question.

Comment: @NigelJ Exactly because they use the Triune God is the reason I'm asking this question. I'm looking for non-Triune Christians. I made an edit clarifying that

Comment: In the mind of Christian thought, you are not really making logical sense. We can not exclude the name of God as not being the Holy Trinity.

Comment: @KenGraham I'm confused. At the very high level I was told that Christians fall into two main categories. Those that believe in Trinity and those don't. e.g. [Which Christian denominations do not believe in the Trinity? Why not?](https://www.quora.com/Which-Christian-denominations-do-not-believe-in-the-Trinity-Why-not) and [Nontrinitarianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontrinitarianism). Are you saying that's not case or something else about the structure of my question? (I'm really try to just understand what _you_ mean)

Comment: The vast majority of Christians believe in the Trinity. This should’ve been made clear at the beginning!

Comment: See [midnight office](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_office) and [nocturns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nocturns). Notice that the quoted text nowhere says that the groups in question worship God alone; indeed, the Qur'an clearly specifies elsewhere that they do worship other figures of Islam as well; your unilateral insertion of the word *alone* in places where it does not seem to actually exist reminds me of [Luther's (re)wording of Romans 3:28](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sola_fide).

Comment: @Lucian Thanks. I'll take a look. In the Islamic view, Christians and Jews are monotheist religions and the notion of trinity is something that came after Prophet Jesus (PBUH). Can you mention which verses in Quran specify that they worship other figures?

Answer (score 1):

**Which sects of Christianity recite verses of God and prostrate to God during the night?**

(This post was made prior to to edits of the original question.)

As indicated in your [Wikipedia link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prostration#Christianity), many Christian denominations practice prostration at various religious services. However, this could be more of a local tradition, within a particular denomination and region where a true set of norms and rules do not exist because it is more or less a private devotional act.

In any case, Christians are not generally in the habit of praying uniquely in the name of God without associating the every essence of God with the name of the MostHoly Trinity. We are Christians after all and the Sacred Trinity is God.

There is a tradition within the Catholic Church in Poland where the polish faithful pray in a prostrate manner. Since it is a personal devotional manner of praying the Church does not regulate what prayers or biblical verse must be recited. Nor does the Church regulate times in which the faithful must pray in this manner.

Pope St. John Paul II often prayed prostrate on the ground, according to Polish tradition.

> Throughout his life, from the first moment of each day to the last, John Paul kept a regimen of deep, fervent devotions that left those around him, even other religious leaders, in awe.
>
> As he said in the early days of his papacy: "Prayer, which in so many ways expresses our relationship to the living God, is the pope's first duty and his first message, the first condition of his service to the church and the world."
>
> During his Vatican years, health permitting, John Paul would spend as many as seven hours a day in prayer, adoration and contemplation. In "Great Souls: Six Who Saved the Century," journalist David Aikman described the routine during the pontiff's prime:
>
> "John Paul II is at prayer in his private chapel by 6:15 a.m., at times prostrate on the floor, at times actually groaning in the travail of intercession. During moments of down time' amid the panoply of solemn public appearances, he again and again closes his eyes, tightens his facial muscles in concentration, sometimes shades his eyes with his hand, and withdraws to that inner, sealed room of his soul where he communicates with God." - [John Paul's fervent prayer inspired awe in others](https://journalstar.com/special-section/news/john-paul-s-fervent-prayer-inspired-awe-in-others/article_d0083952-6780-52a7-a0db-fa91d048ce7a.html)

I am sure many Christians around the world pray in such a manner, but I know of none that regulate it with specific norms outside of very specific religious ceremonies. Thus generally, it would be a private devotional act that some Christians practice privately as they do in Poland. The prayers of biblical verses recited would naturally be left up to the individual.

I see no need why such private devotional acts should be regulated. The Holy Spirit can inspire the faithful to pray the way He desires.

Remember also that Jesus himself prayed in this position, just before his Passion.

> "And he (Jesus) went a little farther, and fell on his face, and prayed, saying, O my Father, if it be possible, let this cup pass from me: nevertheless not as I will, but as thou wilt." - [(Matthew 26:39)](https://biblehub.com/matthew/26-39.htm)

Whether or not some nontrinitarians prostrate themselves at night and invoke the name of God, but not the Trinity seems to be regulated by private devotion also as I can find no source stating rules for such an external observance.

Many nontrinitarians are generally not recognized by Trinitarian Christians as many dream their baptisms as invalid.

> [**Nontrinitarianism**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontrinitarianism) is a form of Christianity that rejects the mainstream Christian doctrine of the Trinity—the teaching that God is three distinct hypostases or persons who are coeternal, coequal, and indivisibly united in one being, or essence (from the Greek ousia). Certain religious groups that emerged during the Protestant Reformation have historically been known as antitrinitarian.
>
> According to churches that consider the decisions of ecumenical councils final, trinitarianism was definitively declared to be Christian doctrine at the 4th-century ecumenical councils,[1](https://journalstar.com/special-section/news/john-paul-s-fervent-prayer-inspired-awe-in-others/article_d0083952-6780-52a7-a0db-fa91d048ce7a.html)[3](https://biblehub.com/matthew/26-39.htm) that of the First Council of Nicaea (325), which declared the full divinity of the Son,[5](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/71841/do-any-christians-sects-have-a-standing-prostration-prayer-like-the-jewish-amid) and the First Council of Constantinople (381), which declared the divinity of the Holy Spirit.[6](https://blogs.ancientfaith.com/walkinganancientpath/2019/03/27/the-spiritual-journey-embodied-prostrations/)
>
> In terms of number of adherents, nontrinitarian denominations comprise a small minority of modern Christians. The largest nontrinitarian Christian denominations are The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints, Oneness Pentecostals, Jehovah's Witnesses, La Luz del Mundo and the Iglesia ni Cristo, though there are a number of other smaller groups, including Christadelphians, Church of the Blessed Hope, Christian Scientists, Dawn Bible Students, Living Church of God, Assemblies of Yahweh, Israelite Church of God in Jesus Christ, Members Church of God International, Unitarian Christians, Unitarian Universalist Christians, The Way International, The Church of God International, and the United Church of God.

More information may be gleaned from the following articles:

- [Do any Christians sects have a Standing/Prostration Prayer like the Jewish 'Amidah' and Muslim 'Salat'?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/71841/do-any-christians-sects-have-a-standing-prostration-prayer-like-the-jewish-amid)
- [The Spiritual Journey Embodied: Prostrations](https://blogs.ancientfaith.com/walkinganancientpath/2019/03/27/the-spiritual-journey-embodied-prostrations/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and elaborating the difference between private practice vs  regulation. Given the abundance of different sects that do this, why are you singling out the 'Catholic Church in Poland'

Comment: Did you not ask about particular Christian denominations or sects?